# Keyboard shortcut under Skype for Business 2016

Tags: ms-office, keyboard-shortcuts, skype-for-business

Till 2015 and earlier versions of Skype for Business and Lync, keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>  + <kbd>Y</kbd>

used to bring up the application window with the focus in search box. After upgrading to Office 2016, the above mentioned shortcut does not work.
Has this shortcut been changed to something else?

Comment: Does `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+3` work for you?

Comment: Yes it does. Another question - how do I press these keys using one hand?

Comment: You can use sticky keys: https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/using-your-keyboard-one-handed-windows-8-1/

Comment: Vote this UserVoice Post in the hopes that someone brings this back https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273497-skype-for-business/suggestions/11101626-bring-back-the-windows-key-y-hotkey

Comment: @aolszowka I am using autohotkey to map the older keyboard shortcut to the newer one. So, now I can again use Winkey + Y under SfB 2016

Comment: In Skype for Business, Ctrl+Alt+Shift+3 does nothing for me, but Win+Y works. (en-UK keyboard if that makes a difference)

Comment: Does anyone know how can I prevent / unbind `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+3` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this moment I have not seen an official response from Microsoft.

The following shortcut was found on [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Skype-for-Business-42ff538f-67f2-4752-afe8-7169c207f659).

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>
>
> Open the main window and put focus in the search box.

Sticky keys function makes you able to use it one-handed:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>  + <kbd>U</kbd> 
   or open `Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center`
2. Select **Make the keyboard easier to use**
3. Select **Turn on Sticky Keys**
4. Adjust the settings:
   [image]